# Redhat openJDK 1.9 (Windows) - "Illegal char" in "java.activation"?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, redhat-openjdk

This is just a 'hello world sort of spring app. I am getting the error:

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'restjpademo'
Information:javac 9.0.0.1-redhatea was used to compile java sources
Information:30/03/2017 09:01 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3s 181ms
Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jrt:\C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0.0-1!\java.activation
```

This is with a fresh install from the openjdk msi download, in intelli-j idea 2017.1, on windows 10 Educational edition (basically 10 Pro but with no Cortana).

This appears to be related to intelli-j's `jdk.table.xml` configuration file *which it autogenerates* when you select openJDK 1.9:

it begins:

```
<application>
  <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="9.0" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;9.0.0.1-redhatea&quot;" />
      <homePath value="C:/Program Files/RedHat/java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0.0-1" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jrt://C:/Program Files/RedHat/java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0.0-1!/java.activation" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1:

- [IDEA-170307](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170307) Cannot compile any plugin in IDEA 2017.1 and JDK9ea

Comment: thank you! I have a bug report on their forum too which likely will get merged now :)

Comment: I notice you work in support at jetbrains - do you happen to know the ETA for the fix 2017.1.2 ?

Comment: ~2 weeks till EAP, ~1 month till the release.